# Can someone explain why my divs are indenting themselves after the first row?

Tags: html, css

Quite a weird problem here. I don't know if it's related, but I am using Shopify - which has been the cause of weird problems in the past.

Okay, so here is the page on which I am coding (not the final place it will be for the record) - http://stonedclassy.com/pages/page2

As you can see, there are 6 divs on the page. I am using Bootstrap, and they are all span6 (meaning they take up half the width of the page on a an averaged sized desktop). The first "row" of divs is perfectly fine, but starting on the second row, there is an indent that I cannot get rid of. It's causing all of the subsequent divs after the first row to be forced onto their own row since they can't fit two to one row.

If I change all the divs size to span5, they are able to fit two to a row, but there is still an indent starting on the second row.

Here is the html:

**Please note that to save space, I am including just ONE of the SIX divs I am referring to. The full code is literally just this code repeated six times**

```
<div class="span6 majorimgtesting">
<a href="">
    <div class="ghostrowforcategories span6"> <button class="ghostbuttonforcategories">TESTING</button> </div>
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0654/2811/products/clear-hammer-bubbler-water-pipe-stonedclassy_large.jpg?v=1422320684" class="imgtesting" />
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0654/2811/products/Micro-Mini-Water-Pipe-Stonedclassy_5571a18d-b3ed-457d-b180-f36cf3acb2b3_large.jpg?v=1423018550" class="imgtesting"  />   
</a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.majorimgtesting
{
  max-height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: .5s ease;
  float: left;
}

.majorimgtesting:hover
{
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgtesting
{
  max-width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index:-1;
}

.ghostrowforcategories 
{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ghostbuttonforcategories
{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666105;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #666105;
  float: middle;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: .8;
}

.ghostbuttonforcategories:hover
{
  background-color: #666105;
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: You should really try not to override the layout properties of your grid. Instead, apply specific styling to elements inside the grid column blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap removes the margin of the first span in a sections of spans so if you place the items like this(as it's on the page)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span-12">
        <div class="sapn-6">...
    </div>
    <div class="span-12">...</div>
    <div class="span-12">...</div>
</div>
```

it would only remove the margin of the first span-12 and the first span-6 and due that the next span-6 within a span-12 that's not the firstone it'll have that margin, so there's why you have that margin problem. Now, to fix it you could remove the class span-12 form the "frame like" divs and your problem will be solved, and the responsive items should still work. Example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div>
        <div class="sapn-6">...
    </div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your `divs` are contained in a single `<div class='row-fluid'>` parent. The first child of every `row-fluid` gets a `margin-left: 0` which is pulling the first element out of line. Each subsequent element gets the regular `margin-left` value so they all line up appropriately.

Comment: That sure is the issue, but what's the solution?

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. How would you suggest fixing it? Whether or not those divs are actually within a <div class='row-fluid'> the problem persists.

Comment: This answer is correct. You're causing issues by having styling and extra elements in the Bootstrap grid. Remove anything between `.row` and `.span*`, and don't apply styles to them. Make sure that columns in any given row total 12 or less. It's worth noting that Bootstrap 3 makes this type of thing much easier. It's more forgiving of row overload.

Comment: Isherwood, perhaps I am still doing something wrong? I have tried several different things based on your suggestion and it doesn't seem to be working.
I have tried changing it to:

    <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">  
  <div class="majorimgtesting">

with no success.

Comment: I just tried putting two of the span6 divs inside a span12 div. This caused them to to be able to fit two to a row, but did not get rid of the indenting issue.